# macOS telnet connection refused

Tags: ssh, putty, telnet, gateway

I use Termius to connect to a gateway, I am able to connect, but the command line is still - I can't write anything there.

I am also trying to connect to a gateway using PuTTY, but the error I keep getting is "Connection refused". I checked my host - it's not down.

When I run talent command on my Mac, I get this:

```
telnet X.X.X.X
Trying X.X.X.X
telnet: connect to address X.X.X.X: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

I have also tried enabling "Remote Login" in system preferences, but it gave nothing.

Overall, I've been following this guide.

So, the question is, how do I use telnet on my macOS to connect to a gateway? Thank you so much. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: telnet is an ancient protocol and very insecure (no encryption, it sends plain-text passwords). Because of that almost any modern device has it disabled by default and uses SSH in stead. It appears your gateway has it disabled as well. Without more information about your "gateway" (what kind of gateway? a brand/model name would help) it is not really possible to give a real answer to your question.

Comment: Hi @Tonny and thanks a lot for your answer :) The gateway I am working with does support telnet - I've double-checked it. 
The gateway I am using is developed by a company I am working at. Basic info about it, if that helps: 
It can communicate via Ethernet and LTE,  supports 4.X/5.0, has 2 LAN ports and controller Wi-Fi. Although, I am not sure this info is very useful right now.

Comment: The device is obviously refusing the connection. Either you are using the wrong ip-address (so you are not connecting to the gateway but to something else) or the telnet service is disabled on the device. If it is a in-house developed device you will have to talk to the developers for more information. We don't know anything about it.

Comment: I checked the IP address and it's the right one. I don't think that the telnet service is disabled because other people connected to it seamlessly with Windows.

Comment: Are you sure it is really telnet and not SSH ? Are you sure the telnet service is running on the default port (23) ? If not on the default port you need to tell the telnet client to which port to connect as well. Last but not least. Your "gateway" is a router from your description. Are you sure you have hooked it up to the local LAN correctly? It probably only exposes its telnet service on the "local LAN" side. It would be stupid to have it running on the 'WAN" interface. So is the router correctly wired to the LAN?

Comment: Yes, I am 100% sure it is really telnet. Yes, I am sure I am trying to connect to 23. Yes, it's definitely wired correctly to the LAN, not WAN.

Comment: Then I'm all out of ideas. For telnet it doesn't really matter what client (or OS) you use. They all should do the same thing. So if a Windows machine can connect a Mac should be able to do the same.

Comment: Thank you @Tonny for your time and attention anyway. :)